# nicescroll not working for page

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Nice Scroll 3.2.0, without any script call what so ever and the css shown below, works as it should with Bootstrap 2.3.4, but it won't work on Bootstrap 3.3.4, with or without a script call. The other jquery files being used are:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.v1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/bootstrap.3.3.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/bootstrap.submenu.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.respond.js"></script>
```

The CSS used is:

```
.nicescroll-rails {
    width: 5px !important;
}
.nicescroll-rails div {
    width: 5px !important;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5) !important;
    border: none !important;
    border-radius: 0 !important;
}
```

I can't get version 3.2.0 or 3.6.0 to work with or without this script call:

```
<script>
$("html").mouseover(function() {
    $("html").getNiceScroll().resize();
});
</script>
```

Any ideas on how to get it to work? Also, does anyone know how to disable it on desktop widths? Thanks in advance.

The jsfiddle is: http://jsfiddle.net/hozey/dmLo6jtp/

Comment: are there any `console errors`??

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the jquery.tmpl.min.js file needed to be added. Hope this helps someone else.